# How to save list as a value in set in Redis

Tags: caching, lua, redis

I am  trying to save a list as value in set for specific keys but could not find any way, Is it possible in redis?. I am not sure weather we can use redis save data like this . If not  please correct me and help to do that.

I want to store sample data like in below format

```
publisher 
     { NAME : Domain,
          //list
          Urls : { 
                    url1,
                    url2,
                 }
         }
   ......................
   .....................
```

Comment: $redis->set("exampleKey", "yourData");

is that what you need? please clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store like this in Redis. Instead you can use a reference of that list inside the value and make use of it.

Here is an example:
I have a hash contains NAME and urls. where urls is a list.

```
hset("publisher","NAME","Domain");
hset("publisher","Urls","UrlsList");
```

When you get Urls from hget("publisher","Urls"). Do an `lrange("UrlsList",0,-1)` this will fetch you all values in that list.